# Form Validations without *ngIf. how can i use form validations(from service) without creating a new div

Tags: angular

How can I use form validations (from service) without creating a new div everytime for validation Error.Eg:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
    <label for="validity" class="input-heading ">Validity*</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p ngIf="myForm.get('validity').invalid">Please provide Validity</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="startMonth" class="input-heading col-md-2">StartMonth</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" class=" from-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="endMonth" class="input-heading col-md-2">EndMonth</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" class=" from-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

--repeated code

```html
<p *ngIf="myForm.get('endMonth').invalid >Please provide End Month</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this repletion by creating a component say `print-error` which take the `control` as `input`.

#### print-error.ts

As of now there is only one `@Input` however if you want to customize further you can add some more `@Input` here.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula';

@Component({
    selector: 'print-error',
    templateUrl: './print-error.component.html',
    providers: []
})
export class PrintError{

    @Input("control")
    private control: any;

}
```

#### print-error.html

Add all kind of validation here. It will apply the error message accordingly.

```
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="control && control.errors && (control.dirty || control.touched)">
     <div><small *ngIf="control.errors.required">This field is required</small></div>
     <div><small *ngIf="control.errors.unique">{{control.errors.unique}}</small></div>
     <div><small *ngIf="control.errors.lessThanValidator">{{control.errors.lessThanValidator}}</small></div>
     <div><small *ngIf="control.errors.greaterThanValidator">{{control.errors.greaterThanValidator}}</small></div>

</div>
```

#### Usage

```
  <input required name="subject" #subject="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="subject">
  <print-error [control]="subject"></print-error>
```

Comment: I want to dynamically add a div below my input field where ever they are applicable for eg if i dont fill name field,i get error for name, the dynamic div should say "Please enter Name"(this msg will come from service)

Comment: You can get the name from `control` in `PrintError`. Or you can add one more `@Input` for name.